# In Main function, after a try block throws an exception how can I make it keep on execute the next try block

Tags: java

In Main function, after a try_block throws an exception the function is supposed to be break.  My question is how can I make it keep on executing to the next try_block. Below I'm giving an example:

```
public static void main(String [] s){
    ABC aBC = new ABC();
    try {
        aBC.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _log.error(ErrorCodeEnum.ERROR,
                "XXXXXXX!!! in " + new Date(),e);
    }
    BCD bCD = new BCD();
    try {
        bCD.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _log.error(ErrorCodeEnum.ERROR,
                "YYYYYYYYYYY!!! in " + new Date(),e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the code above that should prevent the second try block from being called, even if the first block has an exception, unless that exception causes the system to exit.

Comment: Here is the thing: I tried to run this main function, when the first exception was thrown this function got stopped. What I want is to make it keep on executing the rest of the code.

Comment: well what exceptions are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The code should work as it stands - i.e. the second block should still get executed if the first block throws and catches an Exception.

However you might want to consider catching `Throwable` rather than `Exception` if you truly want to catch everything. In particular, [java.lang.Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) is not a subclass of Exception, but is a subclass of Throwable.

Comment: On the other hand, Errors indicate "[serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)".

Comment: Thanks, You Guys. It works now. It's weird when I removed ",e" in line 7, the function worked well. Why is this? Lemme investigate this.

Comment: @Ryan - very true. But sometimes you want to write an unreasonable application :-)

Comment: @mikera: Agreed, but I thought it was worth noting for any junior-ish devs who happen across this answer.

Comment: Both what you guys said are really true and I do need to print those specific information to investigate the exception that been thrown. I'm going to try the finally{} way to do this.... wish me luck!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, you can wrap the statements you want executed in a `finally` block as follows:

```
ABC aBC = new ABC();

try
{
    aBC.execute();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    _log.error(ErrorCodeEnum.ERROR, "XXXXXXX!!! in " + new Date(), e);
}
finally
{
    BCD bCD = new BCD();

    try
    {
        bCD.execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.error(ErrorCodeEnum.ERROR, "YYYYYYYYYYY!!! in " + new Date(), e);
    }
}
```

The statements in the `finally` block will get executed regardless if an exception occurs in the outer `try` block.

Comment: I'm gonna try this one..... hopefully after I finished it won't look too strange. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, You Guys. It's fixed. I didn't change anything. The reason it didn't work at the 1st time I suspect its my IDE got wrong. After I did some testing it works fine now. Thank you for your help. I didn't do the finally{} way because I guess my boss might not like it. Anyway, thank you all!!! ;-)